# LUIS prebuilt entity datetimeV2 resolves wrongly date range

Tags: azure-language-understanding

LUIS doesn't handle the below correctly.

Example utterance:

```
From Friday the 26th until Tuesday the 30th
```

Response:

```
"entities": [
{
  "entity": "from friday the 26th until tuesday",
  "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange",
  "startIndex": 0,
  "endIndex": 33,
  "resolution": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timex": "(2018-01-26,XXXX-WXX-2,P-2.33532467143519D)",
        "type": "daterange",
        "start": "2018-01-26",
        "end": "2018-01-23"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

The date range resolved is not legal, due to a failure to identify "the 30th" as part of the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should note that this doesn't seem to be a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and that the moderators would probably prefer to have you posit an actual question next time as opposed to an observation.

In the future, please submit prebuilt entity-related bugs to our repo, [Recognizers-Text](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/). I've gone ahead and created an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/issues/280) there that stems from this question.

Update (2018/01/31):
This issue has been fixed and is in the pipeline awaiting release, thank you for reporting this!